# Adding Target Line for 2023 Cumulative Costs in Power BI Visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I am seeking assistance with a visual I've created to compare cumulative costs for the years 2022 and 2023.

For the visual, I have developed the following measure for cumulative costs:

```
Cumulative Costs =
CALCULATE(
SUM('Cost 1'[Amount EUR]),
FILTER(
ALL('Calendar'[Date]), // Remove the filter context from the Calendar table
YEAR('Calendar'[Date]) = YEAR(MAX('Calendar'[Date])) &&
MONTH('Calendar'[Date]) <= MONTH(MAX('Cost 1'[Date]))
)
)
```

This measure is placed on the Y-axis, with the Calendar Month on the X-axis, and the Calendar Year as the legend.

My query is about incorporating a target line for 2023 cumulative costs into this visual. Currently, the use of the legend for differentiating between the years is preventing me from adding a secondary Y-axis. Is there a way to work around this issue? Should I create a separate measure to facilitate the addition of the target line?

I have attached a sample of the data and a screenshot of the visual for your reference.

[Sample Visual and sample Dataset Attached:](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IOviSSW_LKRWuyKH_R7Gh6RaDDj6_zZV?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the Line graph visual.
Yes, create a separate measure as you suggested.

Alternative suggestion:
Try the Line and Clustered Column chart - this supports what you need, IF you are okay showing your costs as bars, with target as line (might make it clearer for the user).

Comment: hi I tried that but that is not helpful